# rails 4 multiple ruby arrays with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I'm trying to build a method that pulls an array of arrays, much like nested loops in the view.

I am trying to build a method on my User model that does this:

```
@past_parties = User.parties

<%= @past_parties.each do |past_party| %>
  <%= past_party.guests("email").uniq.each do |guest| %>
    <%= guest.name %> <%= guest.email %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

These are my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :hosts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :parties, through: :hosts

  def past_guests
     self.parties.guests 
  end
end

class Host < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :parties, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :guests, through: :parties

end

class Party < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :host
  has_many :guests, dependent: :destroy

end

class Guest < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :party

end
```

I can get the loop to work in the view, but when I try to build it as a method (so I can call current_user.past_guests, if current_user is an instance of User.),  I get this error

```
undefined method `guests' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

How do I get all of the guests that a user has ever invited without building the loop in the view?

Comment: you are calling instance method past_guests on User class, change the method to class method.

Comment: ah,  no I wrote it wrong...I meant to say current_user.past_guests, not User.past_guests.  I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to access an `array` from another `array`:

```
self.parties.guests
```

`self.parties` returns an `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`, so if you want to get the `guests` of the `parties` you have to loop over the elements.

But since you want only the guests, you can simply change your **user** class to:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :hosts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :parties, through: :hosts
  has_many :guests, through: :parties

  # Call your guests
  def past_guests
     self.guests 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Each party is going to have collection of guests. You need to do this in your method definition:

```
def past_guests
  self.parties.collect(&:guests) 
end
```